# Docker compose : Nginx reverse proxy with multiple containers

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I need to use conteinerized nginx as a reverse proxy to pass all requests/api/* to one service and rest of them to another.
So I have two services in docker containers, accessible by `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3001`.

Also I have a Docker container for proxy server:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen              80;

    server_name         localhost;

    access_log          /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://api1:3000;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1  break;
        proxy_pass         http://api2:3001;
    }
}
```

And docker compose:

```
services:
  api1:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - ID=1
      - GIN_MODE=release

  api2:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    environment:
      - ID=2
      - GIN_MODE=release

  reverseproxy:
    build: ./reverseproxy
    ports:
      - "3333:80"
    depends_on:
      - api1
      - api2
```

Both services `api1` and `api2` are accessible on ports 3000, 3001.
But when I try to access them through proxy: `localhost:3333` and `localhost:3333/api/`, one of them is accessible, but another returns 502 Bad Gateway.

That's more interesting, in real project `localhost:3333/api/` was accessible and `localhost:3333` returns Bad Gateway.
But on simplified [example](https://github.com/DonTomato/nginx_rp) it works vise versa: `localhost:3333` works and `localhost:3333/api/` doesn't.

Any ideas why it happens and how to fix that?

Comment: It looks like `api2` is listening on port 3000, but your `proxy_pass` directive tries to connect to port 3001.  Connections between containers don't use or require `ports:`.

Comment: 3001 is the outside port to reach it from the host. However for services running inside the docker network they should communicate on the inside port which for app2 is port 3000

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks a lot, that was a problem. Could you make it as an answer, and I will mark this question as solved, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connections between containers always use the "normal" port for whatever server is running inside the destination container.  `ports:` aren't used at all, and in fact aren't even required here.

In your case both destination services use port 3000 and you should use that port in your Nginx configuration

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://api1:3000;
    #                              ^^^^
}

location /api {
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1  break;
    proxy_pass         http://api2:3000;
    #                              ^^^^ "normal" port, not mapped `ports:` port
}
```

If access to your services will only be via the reverse proxy, you can delete the `ports:` lines from the `app1` and `app2` services, and they won't be directly reachable from outside the Docker network.  This won't affect connections between containers; this Nginx configuration can remain unchanged.